# My django web app comment form is not displaying properly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add comment function to my blog app and the comment form is not displaying "name, email, body"

[image]

and the submit button when clicked is showing error 405 page not working...

Below is my models.py code

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

Below also is my forms.py code

```
from django import forms
from . import models
from .models import Post, Comment


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("title", "group", "image")


    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields["group"].queryset = (
                models.Group.objects.filter(
                    pk__in=user.groups.values_list("group__pk")
                )
            )

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

Also is the views.py codes

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

def post_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Here also is the urls.py codes

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (PostListView, PostCreateView,
                    PostUpdateView, PostDetailView, PostDeleteView, UserPostListView)
from . import views

#app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name="blog-home"),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name="user-posts"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="blog-about"),

]
```

How can I modify this code to make the comment form to display normally

Comment: Can you add the html code so I can see how your form is set up?

Comment: I just added it to the question...